# How to design and handle big tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Suppose I have a **Games table**, a **Players table**, and a **Game Admin**(Who can add game to system) table , and a **score table** contains game id gamer id and score for each game level.

Each Game has many Players
players are not game admin.
Each Game Admin has a few Games .the score table may be more over 15 million records .

i have 2 idea : please tell me pros and cons

According to my estimation system will not have more than 100 games so :

1.create new table for each game to prevent store all scores in one table

2.keep gamer and players main profile  in one database and create new database for each games?

Which option is more suitable?
Please if you have another idea share with me . 
thank you

Comment: not sure what is the question.  But, are you inspecting us to provide you the code? or what?

Comment: This may be the very rare case where creating databases (or tables) on the fly may be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of the performance of queries, the two solutions are substantially equivalent in that they have as a result the fact of having more tables of smaller dimensions. The only difference is due to three aspects, the first is related to access and connection time or authentication to the database in the case of multiple databases accession to the various boards and routed upstream from dns and in particular from the dbname but thisIt implies that for every access to the table of the game you should prevdere a new connection. In the second case, the use of new connections may be less but you should note that you have to worry about in your code to manage the dynamic identification of the table to be accessed. Finally in the number of databases that you can access you are often subject to restrictions for what concerns the rights of use or the service contract with your provider if you do use hosted solutions.

Comment: please be more clear , i dont really understand what do i should now for this problem?!

Comment: Depend form your need, experience and architecure. Your web application is host by a dataprovider? Have you limit in number in db accessible by your terms of service?.  are you a good programmer? are you a good systems/  db manager? If you are looking for some tips my answer could be useful. If you are in evaluation phase i suggest you a trail period where you test/implement  a prootype of the solution and evaluate a more real scenario..